# Appropriate sql query for join two table

Tags: mysql

Consider that we have two tables like the following tables :

Products TABLE : ( Note only in this table ID is product id )

```
|     ID     |   type_id | 
| ---------- | --------- |
|      1     |     1     |
|      2     |     1     |
|      3     |     1     |
|      4     |     2     |
|      5     |     2     |
```

bundle_product_relation TABLE:

```
| ID | bundle_id | product_id |
| ---| --------- | -----------|
| 1  |     1     |      1     |
| 2  |     1     |      2     |
| 3  |     1     |      3     |
| 4  |     2     |      1     |
| 5  |     2     |      5     |
| 6  |     3     |      1     |
| 7  |     3     |      3     |
```

I want to write a function that takes the `type_id` as input and returns bundles whose their all products have that `type_id`

For example f(1) returns bundles ids : 1 , 3.

Bundle with id 2 has a product with ID 5, which is the `type_id` 2, So does not count as the output of the function.

What is the right query to get this output?

Comment: Did you find any pages on Stack Overflow that demonstrates how to write a JOIN clause?  Stack Overflow has MILLIONS of pages full of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, type_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,2),
(5,2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_bundle;

CREATE TABLE product_bundle
(product_id INT NOT NULL
,bundle_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(product_id,bundle_id)
);

INSERT INTO product_bundle VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(1,2),
(5,2),
(1,3),
(3,3);   


SELECT pb.bundle_id 
  FROM product_bundle pb 
  JOIN products p 
    ON p.id = pb.product_id 
 GROUP 
    BY bundle_id 
HAVING MAX(p.type_id) = MIN(p.type_id) 
   AND MAX(p.type_id) = 1;
+-----------+
| bundle_id |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         3 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a join which will return all results:

```
SELECT *
FROM bundle_product_relation
INNER JOIN products on products.ID = bundle_product_relation.product_id
```

Then you says you need to filter a certain `type_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM bundle_product_relation
INNER JOIN products on products.ID = bundle_product_relation.product_id
WHERE products.type_id=1
```

Lastly, you only seem to be interested in `bundle_id`:

```
SELECT bundle_product_relation.bundle_id
FROM bundle_product_relation
INNER JOIN products on products.ID = bundle_product_relation.product_id
WHERE products.type_id=1
```

I did not do any test on correctness, that is left as an exercise to you.